# Volume of a parallelepiped in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Does there exist a parallelepiped $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ has volume 1 and is spanned by the three vectors $v_1=(1,0,-1,2)^T$, $v_2=(-2,1,-1,1)^T$, $v_3=(1,0,1,1)^T$, and a fourth vector $v_4$? If the parallelepiped $P$ exists, determine the vector $v_4$.

I cannot find a formula for the volume of a parallelepiped in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Is it still the determinant so that I need to solve $$det\pmatrix{1&-2&1&x\\0&1&0&y\\-1&-1&1&z\\2&1&1&w}=1$$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, exactly, it is still the determinant. Note that you will have solutions all along a (translated) hyperplane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively: computing the determinant will yield a polynomial that is linear, in $x,y,z,w$, i.e. you will be looking for points satisfying
$$
-3x-7y+z+2w=1
$$
which simply defines some hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that by rescaling your vector, you can find a solution for any fourth vector such that the determinant is nonzero.  Therefore, a solution must exist if and only if the first three vectors are linearly independent.  As noted by Berci's comment, there will be a translated hyperplane of all solutions, which will be parallel to the span of $v_1, v_2, v_3$.